# Reactjs how to display data from nested json object within the same html code

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

My application fetches data from two api endpoints at the same time and combines the data into a single, nested json object like this:

```
{
"Shop1": [
  {
    "product_name": "Shop 1 Wine", 
    "product_price": "4.99"
  }, 
  {
    "product_name": "Shop1 Wine 2", 
    "product_price": "4.49"
  }
],
"Shop2": [
  {
    "product_name": "Shop 2 Wine", 
    "product_price": "4.99"
  }, 
  {
    "product_name": "Shop 2 Wine 2", 
    "product_price": "4.49"
  }
 ]
}
```

This is how the data is being fetched by reactjs:

```
function App() {



const ListLoading = withListLoading(List);
  const [appState, setAppState] = useState({
    loading: false,
    products: null,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    setAppState({ loading: true });
    const baseUrl = "http://localhost:8080/"
    const searchItem = "wine"
    const shops = [
      "Shop1",
      "Shop2"
    ];
    let urls = [];

    const allUrls = shops.map((shop) => {
      let url = baseUrl + shop + "/" + searchItem;
      urls.push(url)
    });

    function fetchData() {
      const allRequests = urls.map(url =>
        fetch(url).then(response => response.json())
      );
      return Promise.all(allRequests);
    };

    fetchData().then(arrayOfResponses => 
      setAppState({loading: false, products: arrayOfResponses})
    );
  }, [setAppState]);
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <div className='container'>
        <h1>Products</h1>
      </div>
      <div className='repo-container'>
        <ListLoading isLoading={appState.loading} products={appState.products} />
      </div>
      <footer>
      </footer>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Then in the actual page I have this:

```
import React from 'react';
const List = (props) => {
  const { products } = props;
  if (!products || products.length === 0) return <p>No products, sorry</p>;
  return (
    <ul>
      <h1>{products}</h1>
      <h2 className='list-head'>products</h2>
      {products.map((product) => {
        return (
          <li className='list'>
            <span className='{product.shop_name}'>{product.product_name} </span>
            <span className='repo-description'>{product.product_price}</span>
          </li>
        );
      })}
    </ul>
  );
};
export default List;
```

I want to be able to run through each element in the json object and in place of `product.shop_name` place top level value(like shop1 or shop2) and then in span blocks the values relevant to a given shop(like product_name and product_price).

Currently I'm getting the following error:

`Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {Shop1}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`.

How can I get react to loop through each level 1 value and then do the same for level 2 values and display them in html?

Comment: Please add what `arrayOfResponses ` looks like.

Comment: `arrayOfResponses` is the json object as shown at the top of my question. I can access the data for shop1 by accessing `arrayOfResponses[0]`

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is in 7 where you try to render array products as jsx child

Probably you mean to write this, if you want Products text as heading

```
import React from 'react';
const List = (props) => {
 const { products } = props;
 if (!products || products.length === 0) return <p>No products, sorry</p>;
 return (
  <ul>
  <h1>Products</h1>
  <h2 className='list-head'>products</h2>
  {products.map((product) => {
    return (
      <li className='list'>
        <span className='{product.shop_name}'>{product.product_name} </span>
        <span className='repo-description'>{product.product_price}</span>
      </li>
    );
  })}
 </ul>
);
};
export default List;
```

or if you want to show products response on html do this

```
import React from 'react';
const List = (props) => {
 const { products } = props;
 if (!products || products.length === 0) return <p>No products, sorry</p>;
 return (
  <ul>
  <h1>{JSON.stringify(products)}</h1>
  <h2 className='list-head'>products</h2>
  {products.map((product) => {
    return (
      <li className='list'>
        <span className='{product.shop_name}'>{product.product_name} </span>
        <span className='repo-description'>{product.product_price}</span>
      </li>
    );
  })}
 </ul>
);
};
export default List;
```

Comment: Hey Mohit. I mean to got through the json object and display the data accordingly. For example `shop_name` would display `Shop1` and then `product_name` would display a span block for each item nested inside `Shop1`, like `Shop1 Wine` and `Shop1 Wine2`. Then the code would run through `Shop2` and the data nested within it.

Answer (score 1):

From your state products.
You need to first get the keys since this products is not an array but json object.

so in your render

```
return(
 <div>
   <h1>Shop1</h1>
     {products.Shop1.map((item,index)=>
        <span>{item.product_name} </span>
        <span>{item.product_price}</span>
     )}

    <h1>Shop2</h1>
    {products.Shop2.map((item,index)=>
       <div key={index}>
          <span>{item.product_name} </span>
          <span>{item.product_price}</span>
       </div>
    )}
  </div>
)
```

Otherwise you will need to retrieve your data into an array

i.e

```
[
"Shop1": [
  {
    "product_name": "Shop 1 Wine", 
    "product_price": "4.99"
  }, 
  {
    "product_name": "Shop1 Wine 2", 
    "product_price": "4.49"
  }
],
"Shop2": [
  {
    "product_name": "Shop 2 Wine", 
    "product_price": "4.99"
  }, 
  {
    "product_name": "Shop 2 Wine 2", 
    "product_price": "4.49"
  }
 ]
]
```

so you would just do

```
return(
 <div>
     {shops.map((shop,index)=>
        <div>
           <h1>{shop.name}</h1>
            {shop.products.map((product,pos)=>
               <div key={pos}>
                 <span>{product.product_name} </span>
                 <span>{product.product_price}</span>
               </div>
             }
         </div>
     )}
  </div>
)
```

Comment: And what if I don't know the number of `Shop` objects? Is there a way to loop through it?

Comment: Hmm, I keep getting `Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {Shop1}).` Is the way I move the object between `arrayOfResponses` and `products` incorrect?

Comment: Notice that your products is eclosed with { } instead of [ ], so u cannot loop through it as an array until your array of responses return data of type array i.e enclosed with [ ]

Comment: I added `JSON.stringify(arrayOfResponses)` to make the response be enclosed in []. Despite this when I try to run something like `{products.Shop.map((item,index)=>` I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`, which is weird

Comment: Make sure `fetchData()` returns an array, `JSON.stringify(arrayOfResponses)` cannot change the data to array

Comment: When I remove `JSON.stringify` I can access `arrayOfResponses[0]` or 'arrayOfResponses[1]' to get the data about `Shop1`. At the same time running `arrayOfResponses.type` returns undefined. So is it an array or not?

Comment: can u try n create and array say allreponses=[] and for every url request push response into it,  then return it in the Promise

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220306/discussion-between-ochom-richard-and-davidb).